# How do One Way Wall-bangs in CSGO work?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In CSGO there has been this thing called a one way wall bang where you can shoot through a wall one way but not the other. How do they work and why are they in the game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any current one-way wallbangs, but generally they are considered bugs, and if I recall correctly, have been fixed in the past.

As to why they occur:
 - The Source engine calculates damage modifiers per-angle and direction
 - This means that you might actually be getting bullets through on one side but not the other
 - I'm going to go out on a limb and say these are difficult to test without a large sample audience